# Automatic hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink

Is it possible to create "automatic hyperlinks" in the sense that each time I write some word (or set of words) an hyperlink is automatically created? For example I would like that each time I write Schrödinger I have an hyperlink to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schr%C3%B6dinger and the text says Schrödinger. The same as in Wikipedia where you have some words (or sets of words) with hyperlinks.

Comment: tex (other than luatex) isn't really designed for that, you could just use a text-replace in the editor or (more in the tex style) use `\schrodinger` and define that to be `\href{Schrödinger}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schr%C3%B6dinger }` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Run with `xelatex` or `Lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}
\def\Schrödinger{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schrödinger}{Schrödinger}\xspace}
\begin{document}

What \Schrödinger wrote, is important for physics.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could mention that the code you posted works with pdflatex or latex as well as long as you call the macro `\Schrodinger` (or `\Schroedinger` or `\cat` or whatever)

Comment: sure ... but I used `\Schrödinger` :-)   and the other ways were already mentioned in your comment